# Spring Cloud : Zuul throwing "Load balancer does not have available server for client"

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, netflix-zuul, netflix-eureka

I am trying to get a simple microservice to register to the Eureka Server and then have Zuul proxy to the microservice. I got the microservice to register to the Eureka Server. However, whenever I bring the Zuul service up I see that it is not registering to the Eureka Server. Whenever I try to route to the microservice I get the below exception:

> Load balancer does not have available server for client: microservice

I am not able to figure out where the issue is. Any help would be greatly appreciated

Below are my Spring Boot classes for each of these components.

**Microservice Components**

**MicroserviceApplication.java**

```
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = { "some.package.controller", "some.package.service" })
@EnableEurekaClient
@EnableJpaRepositories("some.package.repository")
@EntityScan("some.package.entity")
public class MicroserviceApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MicroserviceApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

**bootstrap.yml**

```
server:
  port: 8090

info:
  component: Core Services

spring:
  application:
    name: microservice
```

**application.yml**

```
eureka:
  instance:
    leaseRenewalIntervalInSeconds: 1
    leaseExpirationDurationInSeconds: 2
  client:
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: http://localhost:8761/eureka/
    healthcheck:
      enabled: true
    lease:
      duration: 5

#some other logging and jpa properties below
```

**Eureka Server Components**

**EurekaServerApplication.java**

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableEurekaServer
public class EurekaServerApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(EurekaServerApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

**bootstrap.yml**

```
spring:
  application:
    name: discovery-server
```

**application.yml**

```
server:
  port: 8761

info:
  component: Discovery Server

eureka:
  client:
    registerWithEureka: false
    fetchRegistry: false
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: http://${eureka.instance.hostname}:${server.port}/eureka/
  instance:
    hostname: localhost
  server:
    waitTimeInMsWhenSyncEmpty: 0
```

**API Gateway Components**

**ZuulGatewayApplication.java**

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableZuulProxy
public class ZuulGatewayApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ZuulGatewayApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public ZuulGatewayPreFilter gatewayPreFilter() {
        return new ZuulGatewayPreFilter();
    }
}
```

**bootstrap.yml**

```
spring:
  application:
    name: api-gateway
```

**application.yml**

```
server:
  port: 8888

info:
  component: API Gateway

eureka:
  instance:
    leaseRenewalIntervalInSeconds: 1
    leaseExpirationDurationInSeconds: 2
  client:
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: http://localhost:8761/eureka/

zuul:
  routes:
    microservice: 
      path: /microservice/**
      serviceId: microservice
```

Comment: What does eureka say (the dashboard and `/eureka/apps`? Is microservice registered? Having such short renewal and expiration times might actually cause churn problems. Have you tried lengthening them?

Comment: What version are you using?

Comment: The microservice is registered just fine, adding the `@EnableEurekaClient` annotation to the Zuul application class solved the issue for me, Zuul is now shown on the eureka dashboard as a registered service and is also proxying to the microservice just fine. I have not specified any specific version but based on Spring Cloud version Camden.SR4.
What would you recommend for the renewal and expiration intervals?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Adding `@EnableEurekaClient` solved this issue. The Zuul application is now discoverable in the Eureka server and is able to route requests.

Answer (score 3):

I had the correct annotation on my Zuul application @EnableZuulClient but still got that error.

The problem was that I started all the applications (Eureka, Zuul and the third application) at the same time instead of doing this one by one. So they all needed time to register. After some time, the error was gone and I could reach my service through Zuul client.

Comment: yes, this is also a possible scenario, it takes 35 seconds to register to Eureka service discovery. However, I don't recollect the post/documentation where I read that though

Answer (score 2):

Wrong spring.application.name might be the reason for this error other than
adding @EnableEurekaClient to the Zuul application class.

Comment: fixed my issue by this comment

Comment: another possible reason as well